EditMode state is not changed (still .inactive)
@Environment(\.editMode) var editMode

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List(viewModel.videos, id: \.id, selection: $selectedVideos) { record in
            ...
        }
        .navigationTitle("Videos")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                if editMode?.wrappedValue == .active { // is never active
                    Button(action: {
                        //
                    }) {
                        Text("Delete Selected")
                    }
                } else {
                    EditButton() // doesn't make editMode active? 
                }
            }
        }

I press Edit button on the toolbar and it just changes its title from "Edit" to "Done" instead of replacing with "Delete Selected" button.
And radio button won't appear as well to select an item in the list

Why are you showing a EditButton conditionally? How would a user exit edit mode?

@Sweeper I will add another button, but it has no relation to the issue

You could try this approach, changing the editMode yourself
using .simultaneousGesture(..) as shown in the code.
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    
    private var isEditing: Bool {
        editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing ?? false  // <--- here
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Testing testing")
                .navigationTitle("Videos")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                           if editMode?.wrappedValue == .active {
                               Button(action: {
                                   editMode?.wrappedValue = .inactive
                               }) {
                                   Text("Delete Selected")
                               }
                           } else {
                               EditButton()
                                   .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded { // <--- here
                                       editMode?.wrappedValue = isEditing ? .inactive : .active
                                   })
                           }
                       }
                }
        }
    }

}

